# Derivative Pricing of an Asset

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, finance, finance-mathematics, black-scholes-pde

The Stochastic Differential Equation that models the change in an asset price is

$$
dS = (12S-sin(S))dt+\frac{\sigma S}{S^2+1}dX
$$

where dX's are random variables drawn from standard normal distribution. What is the Black –Scholes-ish partial differential equation that must be
solved in order to price derivatives of this asset

Comment: Just to clarify: Is $dX$ truly a standard normal variate or is it rather a Brownian motion? If it is the latter, then I think you can proceed with the *usual* Black-Scholes-Merton approach, i.e. set up the portfolio, assume a Delta-Hedge etc; no?

Comment: It's a brownian motion. I would really appreciate of you can show the steps too. Thanks!

Comment: The BS PDE is $O_t  + rSO_S + \frac{1}{2}O_{SS}(dS)^2-rO$. In your case, $(dS)^2$ equals $\frac{\sigma^2S^2}{\left(1+S^2\right)^2}$, so the PDE should be $O_t + rSO_S + \frac{1}{2}O_{SS}\frac{\sigma^2S^2}{\left(1+S^2\right)^2}-rO$